# SDL method , parameter convertion

Tags: c++, methods, sdl

I have a small problem with this method,
this is my code ( I have more code but this is the part that gives me errors)

```
void ranCol( SDL_Surface sprite[], SDL_Rect paste)
{

        SDL_FillRect(sprite[y],NULL,temp);
        SDL_BlitSurface(sprite[y],&paste[y],rScreen(),NULL);
}
```

I get 2 errors

```
error C2664: 'SDL_FillRect' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'SDL_Surface' to 'SDL_Surface *'
error C2664: 'randCol' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'SDL_Surface *[50000]' to 'SDL_Surface []'
```

Can anyone help me get this working?

EDIT: Here is the code incase someone wants to comile it

```
    void randCol(int times, SDL_Surface* sprite[], SDL_Rect paste)
{
    int unsigned temp = 10101;//seed
    for(int y = 0;y < times;y++)
    {
        temp = temp*(y+y+1);
        temp = (temp^(0xffffff))>>2;
        //printf("%x\n",temp);
        SDL_FillRect(sprite[y],NULL,temp);
        SDL_BlitSurface(sprite[y],&paste[y],rScreen(),NULL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always manipulate `pointers` to `SDL_Surface`s... change your function to

```
void ranCol( SDL_Surface* sprite, SDL_Rect paste)
```

I am not sure where your `[y]` comes from!  If it's from an array of `SDL_Surface`, pass a single `SDL_Surface` as a parameter to the function, it will be clearer.

If you want to pass an ARRAY of items, use the following signature:

```
void ranCol(SDL_Surface* sprite[], SDL_Rect paste[])
```

But you will still need to pass your `y` in some way, either as a parameter or as a member / global.

Comment: `SDL_Surface*` is equal to `SDL_Surface[]` in function parameter list, as array slice to pinter.

Comment: that [y] is for a loop but it doesn't interfere with anything

Comment: @Laggy `y` is not in the scope of your function, is it global?

Comment: `y` is ok ,its for a `for` loop

Comment: That `SDL_Surface*` worked but i still get  `error C2664: 'randCol' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'SDL_Rect [50000]' to 'SDL_Rect'`

Comment: @Laggy `y` is _not_ in the scope of your function, you either a) pass it as a parameter or b) make it a member of the class owning `ranCol` but it looks like a global function or c) you make it global.

Comment: the `y` is ok, I didnt include it in the code show above as its not relevant to my question

Comment: @Laggy it is relevant as the code you posted doesn't compile.  Should should also have provided how you call the function, but it can be deduced with the errors you are getting.